# AsyncHttpClient: can not resolve patch android

Tags: java, android, http, asynchttpclient, http-patch

`AsyncHttpClient` can not call patch android.

How to call it thanks!

```
 RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        String URL = "xxxxxx;
        params.put("aaa", aaa);
        params.put("bbb", bbb);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.patch(URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);

            }
        });
```

at line `client.patch` is can not call patch

How to call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are not using the proper import statement. The code looks fine, I see that you are trying to use: [com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html), are you using the following import statement:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
```

**Updated** based on comments/edits:
If you are getting "not able to resolve symbol" message then probably you are not having the proper library version or the library order is not the proper one. Ensure that you are using the proper version and your library is on top of the dependency list (in build.gradle). Maybe it's clashing with another library.

Comment: ummm ,but I added

Comment: @ARR.s Then, please update your question with the error message that your are getting.

Comment: @ARR.s Can you update your question with the message that Android Studio is providing? Or just add an image capture with the error message. It's not clear from "can not call patch" message, what is the issue.